# Error compiling arch mips Android Lazarus

Tags: android, pascal, lazarus

I am creating an application for Android but I need to create libraries .so for ARM and MIPS architectures, arm and managed to do it but for MIPS I could not follow step how to create the compiler crusado for MIPS from this tutorial: http://wiki.freepascal.org/Android

But it doesn't work, it generated me this error I leave the link of the image of the error:

[image: http://postimg.org/image/6yc0aweq7/]

and not be to do and I need to compile for a mips.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be caused to an optimization to cmov (mips/aoptcpu:110 and on), try to disable optimizations (-O-)  ?

```
  C_EQ:
      case p.opcode of
        A_MOV_D: p.opcode:=A_MOVZ_D;
        A_MOV_S: p.opcode:=A_MOVZ_S;
        A_MOVE:  p.opcode:=A_MOVZ;
      else
        InternalError(2014061703);
      end;
```

Please report internal errors to the free pascal bugtracker, Internal Errors are always compiler bugs (though not all are equal in their urgency, depending on if they happen with valid code and if there are workarounds)

Provide the commandline that started the build and the versions of the starting tools. (preferably don't work with screenshots but copy and paste terminal contents)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using toolchain from the Android NDK. This is needed due to differences in libc implementation (glibc vs bionic).

You can download NDK from https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html.

I am not familiar with Lazarus, there might be integrated NDK support (though I doubt it).